# invoke error EditText() null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

I know this maybe a very simple solution but I can't for the life of me get this part of the code working for my symptom checker. Everything else is working flawlessly but the application completely crashes at the diagnosis part method.

Here is part of the java file causing the problem (question activity):

```
public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button2;

private RadioButton radioButton;
private RadioButton radioButton2;
private RadioButton radioButton3;
private RadioButton radioButton4;
private RadioButton radioButton5;
private RadioButton radioButton6;
private RadioButton radioButton7;
private RadioButton radioButton8;
private RadioButton radioButton9;
private RadioButton radioButton10;
private RadioButton radioButton11;
private RadioButton radioButton12;
private RadioButton radioButton13;
private RadioButton radioButton14;
private RadioButton radioButton15;
private RadioButton radioButton16;
private RadioButton radioButton17;
private RadioButton radioButton18;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);


    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            opendiagnosis();
            diagnosispart();
        }
    });

    //Question 1
    radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton); //yes
    radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton20); //no
    //Question 2
    radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton4); //yes
    radioButton4 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); //no
    //Question 3
    radioButton5 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton6); //yes
    radioButton6 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton5); //no
    //Question 4
    radioButton7 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton7); //yes
    radioButton8 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton8); //no
    //Question 5
    radioButton9 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton9); //yes
    radioButton10 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton10); //no
    //Question 6
    radioButton11 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton12); //yes
    radioButton12 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton11); //no
    //Question 7
    radioButton13 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton13); //yes
    radioButton14 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton14); //no
    //Question 8
    radioButton15 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton15); //yes
    radioButton16 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton16); //no
    //Question 9
    radioButton17 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton17); //yes
    radioButton18 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton18); //no
}


public void opendiagnosis() {
    // for all pairs: one of each pair has to be checked
    boolean shouldStartNextActivity = (radioButton.isChecked() || radioButton2.isChecked())
            && (radioButton3.isChecked() || radioButton4.isChecked()) && (radioButton5.isChecked() || radioButton6.isChecked())
            && (radioButton7.isChecked() || radioButton8.isChecked())&& (radioButton9.isChecked() || radioButton10.isChecked())
            && (radioButton11.isChecked() || radioButton12.isChecked())&& (radioButton13.isChecked() || radioButton14.isChecked())
            && (radioButton15.isChecked() || radioButton16.isChecked())&& (radioButton17.isChecked() || radioButton18.isChecked());


    if (shouldStartNextActivity){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, answers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please answer all the questions for an accurate diagnosis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void diagnosispart() {
    EditText text = (findViewById(R.id.textView16));

    String value = text.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, answers.class);
    i.putExtra("Value1", "this is it");
    startActivity(i);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption1", radioButton.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption2", radioButton2.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption3", radioButton3.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption4", radioButton4.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption5", radioButton5.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption6", radioButton6.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption7", radioButton7.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption8", radioButton8.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption9", radioButton9.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption10", radioButton10.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption11", radioButton11.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption12", radioButton12.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    radioButton.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption1"));
    radioButton2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption2"));
    radioButton3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption3"));
    radioButton4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption4"));
    radioButton5.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption5"));
    radioButton6.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption6"));
    radioButton7.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption7"));
    radioButton8.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption8"));
    radioButton9.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption9"));
    radioButton10.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption10"));
    radioButton11.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption11"));
    radioButton12.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption12"));

}
}
```

The intent is then passed to the answers activity where its meant to display in textView16:

```
 public class answers extends AppCompatActivity {

 private Button button7;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answers);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }

    String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
    if (value1 != null) {

        TextView displayintentextra = findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        displayintentextra.setText(value1);
    }

    button7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reset();
        }
    });

}


public void reset() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Questions.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Here is what the logcat says:

```
2020-01-30 08:07:37.581 20275-20275/com.example.mhtapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mhtapplication, PID: 20275
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mhtapplication.Questions.onlick(Questions.java:103)
```

XML file where the edittext view is based:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textView16"
android:layout_width="384dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
android:text=""
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />
```

Comment: > findViewById(R.id.textView16) check if you missed the id? textView16 looks like a textView not an editText.

Comment: in the xml it has been changed to edit text, the id is still textView16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly no need to add extra braces for 
    `EditText text = (findViewById(R.id.textView16));`
It can be written as

```
EditText text = findViewById(R.id.textView16);
```

Also Make sure you have `EditText` as your View in xml Layout or please share xml part also

**Make sure you have Text inside your `text` view before getting Text from it**

**According to your updated code please put `EditText text = (findViewById(R.id.textView16));` after `setContentView()` and then try again.**

Comment: xml file has been added, it seems there is a problem in the 'value' declaration

Comment: possible as you have not setting text in `text` view and trying to `getText()` .It can show `NullPointerException`. Also Why are you connecting View inside method? can you share your full code?

Comment: Problem still occurs, I need to define what value does (it has a grey line underneath it) somehow but have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Your EditText is in `Questions ` class and inside `activity_questions` layout right?

Comment: No its in the Answers class, the intent extra is meant to pass the information from the questions class to the answers class. The answers class then calls the intent and displays the value...

Comment: Wait!! What!!. You are sending Intent from `Question` class to `Answer` class right?

Comment: You don't need to add ` EditText text = (findViewById(R.id.textView16));

    String value = text.getText().toString();` lines inside `diagnosispart()`.

Comment: Anyway you are not using `value` string anywhere. What is the use of `EditText text = (findViewById(R.id.textView16)); String value = text.getText().toString();` this line in your code

Comment: THANK YOU BROTHER, it actually works now. Now I'll add in the diagnosis for each symptom using an if statement once 'yes' radiobuttons are ticked.

Comment: University work, what a nightmare, I have upvoted the question and accepted the solution.

Comment: Thanks and All the best